# Scrapy crawler crawling extra data

Tags: scrapy

I am a newbie in scrapy and just tried to crawl the hackernews. I am able to get the all the links and title from the site but the empty title and link are also getting crawled all along the data. How to avoid this or maybe i have done some error in declaring **xpaths**.

**spider.py**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from hn.items import HnItem

class HNSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "hn"
    allowed_domains = ["https://news.ycombinator.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://news.ycombinator.com/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        sites = selector.xpath('//td[@class="title"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = HnItem()
            item['title'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            items.append(item)
        for item in items:
            yield item
```

**output**

```
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://news.ycombinator.com/> (referer: None)
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=11171475'],
         'title': [u'Backpacker stripped of tech gear at Auckland Airport']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://sivers.org/ws'], 'title': [u'Why was this secret?']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2013/12/how-americans-were-deceived-about-cell-phone-location-data/282239/'],
         'title': [u'How Americans Were Deceived About Cell Phone Location Data']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/12/11/youtube-blocks-game-videos-industry-offers-help/'],
         'title': [u'YouTube Blocks Game Videos, Industry Offers Help']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://blog.fsck.com/2013/12/better-and-better-keyboards.html'],
         'title': [u'Prototype ergonomic mechanical keyboards']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.timmins.net/2013/12/11/how-att-verizon-and-comcast-are-working-together-to-screw-you-by-discontinuing-landline-service/'],
         'title': [u'How AT&T, Verizon, and Comcast are working together to screw you']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://blog.samaltman.com/h5n1'], 'title': [u'H5N1']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.digitaltrends.com/gadgets/parents-dislike-infant-seat-ipad-mount/'],
         'title': [u'Parents Revolt Over Fisher-Price Infant Seat With Face-Level iPad Mount ']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'https://www.fsf.org/news/reform-corporate-surveillance'],
         'title': [u'Reform corporate surveillance']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2013/12/newsheets.html?m=1'],
         'title': [u'New Google Sheets: faster, more powerful, and works offline']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://blogs.marketwatch.com/thetell/2013/12/11/fidelity-now-allows-clients-to-put-bitcoins-in-iras/'],
         'title': [u'Fidelity now allows clients to put bitcoins in IRAs']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://bitmason.blogspot.ca/2013/09/what-are-containers-anyway.html'],
         'title': [u'What are Linux containers and how did they come about?']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/ottawa/canada-post-to-phase-out-urban-home-mail-delivery-1.2459618'],
         'title': [u'Canada Post to phase out urban home mail delivery']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/12/11/fda-antibiotic-idUSL3N0JQ36T20131211'],
         'title': [u'U.S. FDA to phase out some antibiotic use in animal production']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/guix-devel/2013-12/msg00061.html'],
         'title': [u'GNU Guix 0.5 released']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'https://sites.google.com/site/ancientbharat/home'],
         'title': [u'Ancient Indian Texts']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-design-tools-8134180'],
         'title': [u'Responsive design tools']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.keacher.com/1216/how-i-introduced-a-27-year-old-computer-to-the-web/'],
         'title': [u'How I introduced a 27-year-old computer to the web']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://blog.sendtoinc.com/2013/12/11/silicon-valley-internship-j1-visa/'],
         'title': [u'How to intern in Silicon Valley with a J1 visa']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'https://www.crowdtilt.com/campaigns/project-marilyn-part-i?utm_source=HackerNews&utm_medium=HNPost&utm_campaign=ProjectMarilyn'],
         'title': [u'Project Marilyn Part I: Non-Patented Cancer Pharmaceutical']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamuniverse#announcements/detail/1930088300965516570'],
         'title': [u'Steam Machines and Steam Controller shipping to beta participants December 13th']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/an-engineers-guide-to-stock-options'],
         'title': [u'An Engineer\u2019s guide to Stock Options']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.vim3d.com/'],
         'title': [u'Vim3D \u2013 A new 3D vi clone [video]']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://da-data.blogspot.com/2013/12/briefly-profitable-alt-coin-mining-on.html'],
         'title': [u'Briefly profitable alt-coin mining on Amazon through better code']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/intellij-idea-13-brings-a-full-bag-of-goodies-to-android-developers/'],
         'title': [u'IntelliJ IDEA 13 Brings a Full Bag of Goodies to Android Developers']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://crowdmed.theresumator.com/apply/'],
         'title': [u'CrowdMed (YC W13) is hiring a VP of Marketing + Web Dev and Design Interns']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://jh3y.github.io/tyto/'], 'title': [u'Show HN: tyto']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/the-switch/wp/2013/12/10/nsa-uses-google-cookies-to-pinpoint-targets-for-hacking/'],
         'title': [u'NSA uses Google cookies to pinpoint targets for hacking']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'https://access.redhat.com/site/products/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/Get-Beta?intcmp=70160000000cINoAAM'],
         'title': [u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Beta']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'http://thenextweb.com/dd/2013/12/11/digia-releases-qt-5-2-android-ios-support-previews-windows-rt-launches-qt-mobile-edition/'],
         'title': [u'Digia releases Qt 5.2 with Android and iOS support']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/>
        {'link': [u'news2'], 'title': [u'More']}
2013-12-12 11:50:46+0530 [hn] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

You might have noticed from the output that `title[]` and `link[]` are getting repeated all the way along.

How to correct this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways of doing that, i.e.:

1. By scrapy pipelines (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html):
   You can add simple pipeline that will drop item if there is no title or link in it.

   ```
   from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
   class DropEmptyPipeline(object):
       def process_item(self, item, spider):
           if "title" in item and "link" in item:
               return item
           else:
               raise DropItem("Missing title or link in %s" % item)
   ```
2. By  not adding item to items collection of it does not have title or link:

   ```
   if "title" in item and "link" in item: 
       items.append(item)
   ```